# Calling a Grails GSP from 2 different controllers

Tags: grails, model-view-controller

I have a GSP that will be rendered from a `FizzController`, but that contains JavaScript code that needs to send AJAX calls back to a `BuzzController`.

My current project directory structure:

```
myapp/
    grails-app
        controllers/
            myapp/
                FizzController.groovy
                BuzzController.groovy
        views/
            fizz/
                mainPage.gsp
            buzz/
                buzz.gsp

        <normal grails-app dir>
    src/
    web-app/

    <normal directory structure for Grails app>
```

The `FizzController#index` method that renders the GSP:

```
def index() {
    render(view: "buzz", controller: "buzz", model: fetchAndInjectModel())
}
```

When I run this and go to `http://localhost:8080/myapp/fizz`, I would expect it to render my GSP. Instead I'm getting one of my custom "page not found" pages. Nothing in the app logs. Any ideas as to what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `render` method has no parameter `controller`, so you need to use something like:

> render view: '/buzz/buzz', model: fetchAndInjectModel()

docs: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/render.html

Other option is do a redirect:

> redirect(controller:"buzz",action:"buzz")

Comment: Thanks @vcarvalho (+1) - is there any way to pass a `model` inside that redirect?

Comment: @smeeb no, but you can pass, for example, the `id` of your model or some other parameter that you need. Usage: [http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Controllers/redirect.html)